# No resource identifier found for attribute 'depurables' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

I finished of developing my app but when a try to generate a singned APK Android Studio shows:

> Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'depurables' in package 'android'

I remove de `android:depurables="true"` (I know that I should let the identifier there but I whanna try) but Android Studio put it again in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mosaicogeek.skintigth.learning.vochostest"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="Beta 2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:depurables="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Vochos"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="mosaicogeek.skintigth.learning.vochostest.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity"
            android:label="RecyclerViewTestActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I try adding `android:debuggable="true"` under `<aplication`  but Android Studio delet it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an attribute called depurables, which is why you get that error.  I doubt Android Studio would be auto adding that back in the manifest.  Find all occurrences of "depurables" in your project to see if you get a hint of what is going on.  Edit-->Find-->Find In Path

Comment: thanx this works!, I read that I shloud put `android:depurables="false"` in the manifes before generate the singed